# Функция, которая возвращает рандомную переменную

Tags: php

```
function random () {
$p1 = "1";
$p2 = "%";
$p3 = " ";
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала рандомную переменную с цифрой, спецсимволом или просто с пустым местом?

Comment: зачем вам такой функционал? пусть просто возвращает значение, а переменную вы создадите сами.

Comment: @Manitikyl расклад такой: нужна функция, которая возврашает либо рандомное число, либо рандомный спецсимвол, либо ничего. Чтобы удобно было работать с маской пароля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более лучший вариант:

```
function random(){
    $array = array(
        "1",
        "%",
        " ",
    );

    return $array[array_rand($array)];
}

echo random();
```

Answer (score 3):

Создаете массив необходимых значений, и выдаете случайное из него:

```
<?php

function random(){
    $array = array(
        "1",
        "%",
        " ",
    );

    $r = rand(0, (count($array) - 1));
    return $array[$r];
}

echo random();
```